# Office web app works on one site collection but not another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, certificate

I have a SharePoint set up with two site collections:

site1.company.com
site2.company.com

I also have an Office Web App server that is currently working with the first site collection. I can click on PPT/Word/etc. documents in the first site and it will open it up in Office Web Apps.

When I try to open up documents in Office Web Apps on site2, I get the following error:

```
“WOPICheckFile,WACSERVER HttpRequestAsyncException [url:https://site2.company.com/spin/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/files/XXXXXX?access_token=REDACTED_XXXX&access_token_ttl=XXXX, e:Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.HttpRequestAsyncException: 
No Response in WebException ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> 
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.    
at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)     -
-- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.HttpRequestAsync.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     -
-- End of inner exception stack trace ---, host correlation:]”
```

The weird thing is that I am able to open Excel spreadsheets without a problem. Word/PPT/PDF/etc. are not working though. Opening up any document in the desktop office app also works fine.

I made sure that I have a working certificate for site #2 (cert is for domain *.site2.company.com).

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using http for SharePoint you need to set AllowOAuthOverHttp to true. you can do this in SharePoint Management Shell using the following commands:

```
$config = (Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig)
$config.AllowOAuthOverHttp = $true
$config.Update()
```

For more information check [this link](https://ntsystems.it/post/office-2013-web-apps)

Comment: I am using HTTPS. When I do Get-SPWOPIBinding, it lists various Office applications. Some of them have a WopiZone of internal-https and others have external-https. Do I need to make sure that all of them have internal-https?